# Как в WebView вывести изображение из внутренней папки drawable?

Tags: android

Cуть проблемы: Eсть в ресурсах `drawable`, в `drawable` вложенны папки с изображениями разных категорий для того, чтобы их сгруппировать, так как их много. Но не знаю как вывести изображение с внутренних папок наподобие drawable/сars, drawable/bike, drawable/aircraft, ...

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXT_TextToShow="тест";
    private WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);


        String my_cells2  = EXT_TextToShow;

        web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView10);

        web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/cars",
            "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head> <body>"
                    + my_cells2+
                    "<p><b>это жирный текст</b></p>"+
                    "<img src=\"image010.png\">"
                    +"</body></html>",
            "text/html", "utf-8", "");

    }
}
```

Не выводится изображение

Comment: В папке drawable нельзя создавать подпапки. Система не увидит ваши картинки из этих подпапок.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в src указать путь полный. У меня так работает:

```
src='file:///android_res/drawable/pic.png'
```